# Splitting a Map instance into two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to split an instance of `Map` into separate arrays. An example of the `Map` instance I have:

```
new Map([
    ["Guatemala", 7],
    ["Albania", 7],
    ["Finland", 3],
    ["Canada", 12],
    ["Japan", 21],
    ...
]);
```

There's more data, but just wanted to show a small sample.

I produced it from the raw data I get from an API in JSON format:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    import_country: "Argentina",
    model: "riolet",
    make: "Audi",
    sold_by: "Huey Bagster",
    sale_price: 18643,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    import_country: "China",
    model: "MKX",
    make: "Lincoln",
    sold_by: "Wolf Coller",
    sale_price: 16850,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    import_country: "Portugal",
    model: "Coupe Quattro",
    make: "Audi",
    sold_by: "Doroteya McLewd",
    sale_price: 13733,
  },
]
```

So I took the `import_country` and counted the number of times it appeared and created `map` as an instance of `Map`.

In order to get the keys and values of `map` in separate arrays, I tried the following:

```
map.forEach(key, value){
                    country.append(key);
                    numCountry.append(value);
                }
```

where `country` and `numCountry` are separate arrays.

My end desired output is:

```
country = ["Guatemala", "Albania"...] and 
numCountry = [7, 7, ...]
```

Comment: Doesn't look like an ES6 map, what format does the data come in?

Comment: The data from the API comes from a JSON array format. The example is what happens after I put the data required in a javascript map and console log map. @Viney

Comment: Can you post a part of that json?

Comment: Done, please see edits above @Viney

Comment: `=>` is not JSON syntax. Looks like PHP associative array syntax.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JSON syntax. The part where {"Country" => number} is shown after I console log my map function to get the number of times a country is parsed from the data.

Comment: So you are counting countries? You never mentioned that...

Comment: I thought I did at the bottom of the post. My desired output is two lists: one for the country and the other list for the number of times that country appears from the data.

Comment: so much confision :-D

Comment: And your map, what is it? Is it a plain object, or is it maybe an instance of `Map`?

Comment: I believe it's an instance of Map. I have var map = new Map();

Comment: OK, that is also crucial information. It should have been in the question. We cannot guess it from the `=>` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map is an instance of `Map`, then use its `keys` and `values` methods:

```js
const map = new Map([
    ["Guatemala", 7],
    ["Albania", 7],
    ["Finland", 3],
    ["Canada", 12],
    ["Japan", 21],
]);
const countries = [...map.keys()];
const numCountries = [...map.values()];
console.log(countries);
console.log(numCountries);
```

Comment: Yep this one worked perfectly. Didn't know I could do that directly in JS. I thought I had to do a foreach loop or something to get the key value pair to separate lists.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly take as sample, modify according to your need.

You can use `Object.reduce(data)` to loop over data and update count for countries.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    import_country: "Argentina",
    model: "riolet",
    make: "Audi",
    sold_by: "Huey Bagster",
    sale_price: 18643,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    import_country: "China",
    model: "MKX",
    make: "Lincoln",
    sold_by: "Wolf Coller",
    sale_price: 16850,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    import_country: "Portugal",
    model: "Coupe Quattro",
    make: "Audi",
    sold_by: "Doroteya McLewd",
    sale_price: 13733,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    import_country: "Portugal",
    model: "Coupe Quattro",
    make: "Audi",
    sold_by: "Doroteya McLewd",
    sale_price: 13733,
  },
];

const map = data.reduce((m, { id, import_country }) => {
  if (!m[import_country]) m[import_country] = 0;
  m[import_country] += 1;
  return m;
}, {});
console.log(map);
const counties = Object.keys(map)
const numCounts = Object.values(map)
console.log(counties)
console.log(numCounts)

//OR:

let countries2 = [],
  numCountries2 = [];
Object.entries(map).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  countries2.push(key)
  numCountries2.push(value)
});
console.log(countries2);
console.log(numCountries2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to an array then just loop and push id of each item on country **code** array and name on **ct** array

```js
var str = `[
   {
  "id": 1,
  "import_country": "Argentina",
  "model": "riolet",
  "make": "Audi",
  "sold_by": "Huey Bagster",
  "sale_price": 18643
   },
   {
  "id": 2,
  "import_country": "China",
  "model": "MKX",
  "make": "Lincoln",
  "sold_by": "Wolf Coller",
  "sale_price": 16850
   },
   {
  "id": 3,
  "import_country": "Portugal",
  "model": "Coupe Quattro",
  "make": "Audi",
  "sold_by": "Doroteya McLewd",
  "sale_price": 13733
   }
 ]`

var arr = JSON.parse(str);
var ct   = [];
var code = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  ct.push(arr[i].import_country);
  code.push(arr[i].id)
}

console.log(ct); //countries
console.log(code); //codes
```